# I can't select app from from Personal profile

Tags: android-11, work-profiles, poweramp

I have installed the Poweramp app

[image]

in my Personal profile via Play Store. However, when I try to add a Music folder, I can only select folders from my work profile

[image]

the following toast appears: You're using this app on your work profile.

[image]

Build number: 939

Android 11

RedMagic OS V4.5

Comment: The toast message indicated that it's installed on the work profile. Just to be sure that you installed this app from your personal Play Store, not your work profile's Play Store? Usually, there's a small icon indicating work profile apps

Comment: Hi @AndrewT.,  My Personal and Work profile have different Google Accounts. I already tried reinstalling the app in my Personal profile. I have uploaded an image above showing it's not installed in the Work profile.